# Adding up observations with similar index and x-values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which has date time data as the index, and a few variables, but only two are relevant here - 'price' and 'quantity'. [link to screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaZfT.png)

So what I am trying to achieve here is to merge the highlighted observations together by summing up the quantity. Problem being, there may be instances when trades are done at the same time on different prices, and I only want to merge the observations if:

1. index is the same, AND
2. price is the same.

And to be clear, I would want to modify the entire dataset PERMANENTLY based on the conditions listed above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't even see a question here

Comment: sorry I accidentally submitted the post by pressing enter.

Comment: Please include some sample data in the text of your question, and the code you have so far.

Comment: sample data is in the screenshot, and I've only tried using groupby with the time index but it does not take into account the different prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
#Write here the code that brings in your data
data=pd.DataFrame(oldData)
newdata=data.groupby(['index','price']).sum().values
```

Comment: Thanks! The df.sum() method is exactly what I was looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the dataset is a list fill with `NamedTuple`s. You can use groupby from itertools to filter by datetime and price.

```
from itertools import groupby

after_merge = []

for _, group in groupby(dataset, key=lambda item: (item["datetime"], item["price"]):

    quantity = sum(item["quantity"] for item in group)

    record = group[0]

    record["quantity"] = quantity

    after_merge.append(record)
```